# How to get the position of an item in the realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the position of an item in the database, along with the data.

```
.ref("users")
.orderByChild("email")
.equalTo(myEmail)
.once("value", snapshot => {
    console.log("Database Position", ???? )
}
```

Is there a value in the snapshot that I could use that indicates the position in the database (after ordering by email)?  I don't want to do this on the client side since I have >1k users

Comment: Answer below. Since this may indeed not work for you, you might want to explain what you're trying to accomplish here. As it stands your question reads like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and if we know the actual goal we may be able to come up with an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase Realtime Database does not track the position of nodes in their parents, nor does it return such a position in query results. This means the only way to determine the position of a child within a set of child nodes, is to retrieve all child nodes before the one you're looking for.

```
.ref("users")
.orderByChild("email")
.endAt(myEmail)
.once("value", snapshot => {
    var index = 0;
    snapshot.forEach(function(childNode) {
        if (childNode.child("email").val() === myEmail) {
            console.log("Database Position", index);
        }
        else {
            index = index + 1;
        }
    });
}
```

Since you commented that you're trying to create a leaderboard, see:

- [Leaderboard ranking with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720997/leaderboard-ranking-with-firebase)
- [Unity - Firebase realtime database - Get my rank in leaderboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961118/unity-firebase-realtime-database-get-my-rank-in-leaderboard)
- [Getting rank of user from firebase database in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128031/getting-rank-of-user-from-firebase-database-in-android)

I'd also recommend checking out Dan's answer on [Leaderboard ranking with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720997/leaderboard-ranking-with-firebase), which also shows ways to store each player's rankings. While that post is about Firestore, the same principles and considerations apply when implementing a leaderboard on Firebase's Realtime Database.

Comment: Thanks Frank, this is unfortunate.  I have a list of >1k users that are ranked (by 'Score').  I was hoping I could use the position in the database to use as their rank.  I suppose the best method would be to run a firebase function once per day to update a rank field.

Comment: I added links to some previous answer about leaderboards and ranking.